# Listening a queue using html

Tags: java, applet

I have a listener code which is listening to a queue and printing the messages on the console. This happens in real time. (Which means, as soon as the messages come to queue it is consumed by the listener and displayed on the console at the same time)

Now the requirement: I want to show the message on the html and it should happen in real time.( i.e. without using polling or refresh (F5)).

Is it possible with using applet ? (I thought to create my listener code as an applet and update the html but not sure if I can update the html from applet)

Is there any other option to achieve this requirement?

I hope I'm able to convey the requirement!!

same query is posted in Oracle forum : https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2382740&stqc=true

Thanks in advance.
chand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your able to call a javascript function from the applet to update your page.

Tutorial: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0172.html